# GDB: Breakpoint that breaks only after a different breakpoint is hit

Tags: gdb

Say I create two breakpoints, 2 and 3. Breakpoint 3 is on line 10, which is executed frequently through the program. How can I configure 3 to break only after 2 has been hit once?

Answer (score 13):

with a simple example:

```
void bp2() { };
void bp1() { bp2(); }

int main()
{
  bp2();
  bp1();
  return 0;
}
```

we can create a breakpoint which only triggers when bp2 is called through bp1 with something like the following:

```
break bp1
break bp2

commands 1
silent
enable 2
c
end

commands 2
disable 2
end

disable 2
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: @user1299784 maybe, you can possibly get the effect that you want through the use of a condition like "break foo if x == 5" in the simple code i posted with no arguments/variables creating state i'm not aware of another way, there is 'ignore 2 n' if you know the number of times breakpoint 3 will be hit before breakpoint 2 is hit, you can just set 'n' to the appropriate amount (the easiest way to get this is by setting a breakpoint on bp1) running it and using "info b" and seeing the 'already hit n times' if the number is stable.

Comment: You can create local state in gdb using convenience variables, so stuff like "set var $bp1hit = 1" and "break bp2 if $bp1hit"

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that you can also create a new breakpoint in the `command` of another breakpoint.

```
b main.c:12
command 1
  b main.c:10
  disable 1
end
```

However, I would advise to generally use [@matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976858/3465171) approach as it is cleaner and leaves less room for confusion.